# Warmings with a dataframe before use xgb

Tags: r, dataframe, xgboost, r-caret, r-package

I prepared a dataset before passing the data to the gb algorithm.

```
[1] "data.frame"
Warning messages:
1: In get(results[[i]], packages[[i]]) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In get(results[[i]], packages[[i]]) :
  internal error -3 in R_decompress1
3: In get(results[[i]], packages[[i]]) :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
4: In get(results[[i]], packages[[i]]) :
  internal error -3 in R_decompress1
```

Then, I trained the model an got this issue.

```
Error in train(NL_Load_Actual ~ ., data = filter_train, method = "xgbLinear",  : 
  lazy-load database '/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/caret/R/caret.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In train(NL_Load_Actual ~ ., data = filter_train, method = "xgbLinear",  :
  restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In train(NL_Load_Actual ~ ., data = filter_train, method = "xgbLinear",  :
  internal error -3 in R_decompress1
```

Comment: Can't see what you actually did

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.